# regular expression negative group

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying, in a regular expression, to match and capture any word that contains "ball" without having "foot" or "basket" in front of it.
for example, I want to match "volleyball" and "dodgeball" but not "basketball" or "football".
important thing is that I can't use a positive group but a negative one.
what I tried:

```
[^(?:foot|basket)(ball)]

!(?:foot|basket)(ball)
```

finding the opposite is rather simple:

```
(?:foot|basket)(ball)
```

but that's not what I'm looking for. I need it the other way around.

EDIT: this is php, it's a "preg_replace" command.

Comment: There's more than one regex syntax. You can't just ask a question about "regex" without describing the language or library it's for use with. PCRE (and if so, Perl's implementation? Python's? Java's?)? BRE? ERE? RE2?

Comment: You're looking for what is called a "negative lookbehind", which is `(?<!....)` in most RE engines (JavaScript doesn't support it).

Comment: @Charles I don't see why backtracking has to be involved in the implementation; while parsing the input string, it can be checked against the negative lookbehind expression at the start of the regex. If it matches, the regex fails.

Comment: @Kenney, if we restricted negative lookbehind to be allowed only in starting position, that would be a different feature. That said, my claims were incorrect, and I retract them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Allright - I did get what you were saying though, several implementations would have trouble doing it efficiently which is probably why they don't all support it.

Comment: @Kenney, indeed; see https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html for a great intro. (Short form: Traditional regex implementations, dating back to the 60s, were compiled to finite-state automatons, guaranteed to complete in constant time; the fancy new ones that popped up in the 90s, generally speaking, had no performance guarantees -- but added fancy features such as the ones you're using here).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Interesting read, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

PHP uses PCREs. Thus, negative lookbehind syntax is available:

```
(?<!foot|basket)ball
```

Answer (score 0):

I would isolate all substring's `ball`, then enforce no foot or basket behind it.

`\b(?:(?!ball)\w)*(?:(?<!foot)(?<!basket)ball(?:(?!ball)\w)*)+\b`
or, I think pcre can do the assertion this way
`\b(?:(?!ball)\w)*(?:(?<!foot|basket)ball(?:(?!ball)\w)*)+\b`

Formatted:

```
 \b 
 (?:
      (?! ball )
      \w 
 )*
 (?:
      (?<! foot )
      (?<! basket )
      ball
      (?:
           (?! ball )
           \w 
      )*
 )+
 \b
```

Comment: interesting.
but why? what's the advantage of this ?

Comment: @john_black - Advantage over what? This `(?<!foot|basket)ball` ? First thing is it matches a word the substring _ball_ is in. The other just matches _ball_. Second is it checks the entire word for all occurances of the substring _ball_. Surprisingly, SO is the kind of place the other answer gets 3 upvotes (maybe no surprise).